# Qt CMake gives mainwindow.h no such file error

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, qt5

I am trying to build CMake file with Qt5. CMake works well on Linux but not on Windows. Qt version 5.10.1. CMakes gives an error on build:
**moc: /cygdrive/c/.../mainwindow.h: No such file**

How could this error be solved?

Folder structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── mainwindow.cpp
├── mainwindow.h
└── mainwindow.ui
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(random_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories.
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Add Qt CMake path.
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\5.10.1\\msvc2015\\lib\\")
# Add a compiler flag.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")

# Find the QtWidgets library.
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

# Generate code from UI files.
qt5_wrap_ui(UI_HEADERS mainwindow.ui)

# Tell CMake to create the executable.
add_executable(random_project main.cpp mainwindow.cpp ${UI_HEADERS})

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(random_project Qt5::Widgets)
```

Comment: You need to add **all** headers to the `add_executable` call. `moc` does not perform a dependency analysis of your sources.

Comment: Tried `add_executable(instant_translator mainwindow.h main.cpp mainwindow.cpp  ${UI_HEADERS})`, same error.

Comment: Did you use the cmake package from cygwin or the windows package? When using Cygwin you need the first one.

Comment: Yes, I'm running through CLion C:\Users\user\.CLion2017.3\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\random_project\cmake-build-debug --target random_project -- -j 2

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with CLion :(

Comment: CLion actually uses C:\cygwin64\ files.

Comment: Try adding `target_include_directories(random_project ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` or `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})`. IIRC, older CMake versions needed this for automoc to work properly.

Comment: I've got the same error :(

Comment: Problem is not related with CLion.

Comment: please avoid to use `qt5_wrap_ui` and use `set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)` or `set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)`
cf https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC.html#prop_tgt:AUTOUIC

Comment: Also you can use `find_package(Qt5  REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)`...

Comment: do you have a `QOBJECT` macro in `mainwindows.h` ?

Comment: Answering first question: tried, same issue. Also, I think `qt5_wrap_ui` is not a problem because it perfectly runs on Linux. Answer to the second question: tried, same. To the third question: I am using `Q_OBJECT` in `mainwindows.h`.

Comment: I don't get this error if I'm using MinGW in Qt directory (`C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32`). But now I'm having other problem: program builds correctly but when it is launched, it does't pop up and it shows `C:\random-project\cmake-build-debug-mingw\random_project.exe

Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)`. Maybe do you know why this error appears?

Comment: I tried to compile also in console, simular resuls. But it's strange that in Qt Creator it works well.

Comment: @vre I think you are right by saying it is CLion problem.

Comment: I think it's the combination of Windows Qt SDK, Cygwin CMake and Cygwin. The Qt SDK contains executables that only run on Windows and do not understand Cygwin paths. But CMake configures your project by calling `moc` with a Cygwin path. At least this is was the error message is trying to tell you. Maybe my previous advice using Cygwin CMake was wrong and you should try Windows installation of CMake. What compiler are you trying to use on Cygwin? Your installed Qt SDK only works with MSVC2015. If you want to use a different compiler you need the appropriate Qt SDK for that compiler.

Comment: Now I am using MinGW from Qt folder. Not is is CLion problem because I can't add qmake as make path compiler in CLion.